# cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'keras.utils'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

when I use 'import talos' I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mirijam/Desktop/rp/RNN_classification/classification.py", line 4, in <module>
    import talos
  File "C:\Users\Mirijam\Desktop\rp\venv\lib\site-packages\talos\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Mirijam\Desktop\rp\venv\lib\site-packages\talos\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .sequence_generator import SequenceGenerator
  File "C:\Users\Mirijam\Desktop\rp\venv\lib\site-packages\talos\utils\sequence_generator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.utils import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'keras.utils' (C:\Users\Mirijam\Desktop\rp\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py)
```

My keras version is 2.5.0. My other Keras imports seems to be working.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to replicate your issue, you can refer working code as shown below

```
import talos
import keras

print(talos.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)

from keras.utils import Sequence
```

Output:

```
1.0.0
2.5.0

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-064232ea7706> in <module>()
----> 1 from keras.utils import Sequence # it wont work

ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py)
```

**Fixed code:**

From `Tensorflow 2.x` onward, `keras` is no longer maintained and it became a part of `Tensorflow`. I would recommend instead of `import Sequence` from `keras`, you should try from `tensorflow` as shown below

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
```

For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence).

Comment: In my case the error still persisted and I needed to uninstall and reinstall keras accordingly to the tensorflow version. Then the solution proposed here worked fine, even if my editor says that `tensorflow.keras.utils` can not be resolved.