# how to import "balanced_batch_generator"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, imbalanced-data

I want to import " balanced_batch_generator" by below code. but it gives an error as below. I was wonder if someone helps me

Error:
AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'Sequence'

```
from imblearn.keras import balanced_batch_generator
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67724133/14290681) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Keras is now integrated into 2.x versions of Tensorflow, you might try this:

Replace

```
from imblearn.keras import balanced_batch_generator
```

with

```
from imblearn.tensorflow import balanced_batch_generator
```